# How to check if a customPrincipal is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have a customPrincipal which I use to set the username in on of my razor files. My issue is that when I open run the project, it tries to access that field in the razor page and since I didn't log in yet, I get `object reference is not set to an instance of an object`. After I log-in, that error goes away because the username token has been set.

[image]

Now, I want to make it so that if the username field is null (the user isn't logged-in) it doesn't access it

Here is my code:

***CustomPrincipal.cs***

```cs
 public class CustomPrincipal : ICustomPrincipal
    {
        public CustomPrincipal(string username)
        {
            Identity = new GenericIdentity(username);
        }

        public string currentUsername { get; set; }
    }
```

***ICustomPrincipal.cs***

```cs
public class ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        public string currentUsername { get; set; }
        public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }
        public bool IsInRole(string role) { return false; }
    }
```

***NavigationBar.cshtml***

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <span class="d-inline-block float-left user-icon pt-0"><i class="fas fa-user fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="d-inline-block"><p class="mb-0">@((User as AE.Web.Gwic.Models.CustomPrincipal).currentUsername)</p></span>
</a>
```

I tried using the following but it gave the same error as well. ***Can someone shed some light onto my issue?***

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 <span class="d-inline-block float-left user-icon pt-0"><i class="fas fa-user fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
 @if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((User as AE.Web.Gwic.Models.CustomPrincipal).currentUsername))
   {
    <span class="d-inline-block"><p class="mb-0">@((User as AE.Web.Gwic.Models.CustomPrincipal).currentUsername)</p></span>
   }

</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is you are trying to access currentUsername on a null object (which is why the exception is thrown). The solution would be to check if the actual is object is null rather than currentUsername:

```
@if (AE.Web.Gwic.Models.CustomPrincipal != null) {
    <span class="d-inline-block">@((User as AE.Web.Gwic.Models.CustomPrincipal).currentUsername)</span>
}
```